# Jcarousel fx:none?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Anyone know how to remove the slide effect from Jcarousel lite? I want it to just change my images with no effect

Answer (score 0):

You need to use easing with "def" parameter. You need to add easing plugin for this. [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Comment: I have the easing plugin working, but when I set it to easing: "def"...my carousel doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Does using the `animation : 0` (zero) [option](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/#Configuration) during initialization not help you?